# Same array is populating in table.

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am building a expandable collapsable table view sample project. Where I have four fields. 
When I click on the cells it expands and shows that field's details. 
I have taken 5 arrays for the fields and details.
The problem I am facing is when I tap on any cell it is showing the same details every time. But I want to show that field's detail on which I am tapping.
I think the problem is in my checkin which I have done in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

This is my code

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *arrSelected;
    NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndex;
    BOOL *isTwoTaps;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.arrFields = @[@"Personal Info", @"Education", @"Hobbies", @"Interest"];
    self.arrPersonalInfo = @[@"First Name", @"Last Name", @"Age", @"Phone Number",@"Address"];
    self.arrEducation = @[@"10", @"10+2", @"Graduation", @"Masters", @"Higher Studies"];
    self.arrHobbies = @[@"Sports", @"Cooking", @"Music", @"Gardening", @"Fishing"];
    self.arrInterest = @[@"Collection", @"Space", @"Medical", @"Engineering", @"Programming"];
    [self.tableView allowsMultipleSelection];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.arrFields count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"CellA";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    UIView *vw=(UIView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:999];
    UILabel *lblField = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    lblField.text = [self.arrFields objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UILabel *lblDetail1 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
    UILabel *lblDetail2 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
    UILabel *lblDetail3 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:4];
    UILabel *lblDetail4 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:5];
    UILabel *lblDetail5 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:6];

    if([self.arrFields objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]) {

        lblDetail1.text = [self.arrPersonalInfo objectAtIndex:0];

        lblDetail2.text = [self.arrPersonalInfo objectAtIndex:1];

        lblDetail3.text = [self.arrPersonalInfo objectAtIndex:2];

        lblDetail4.text = [self.arrPersonalInfo objectAtIndex:3];

        lblDetail5.text = [self.arrPersonalInfo objectAtIndex:4];


    }
    else if ([self.arrFields objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+1]){

        lblDetail1.text = [self.arrEducation objectAtIndex:indexPath.0];

        lblDetail2.text = [self.arrEducation objectAtIndex:1];

        lblDetail3.text = [self.arrEducation objectAtIndex:2];

        lblDetail4.text = [self.arrEducation objectAtIndex:3];

        lblDetail5.text = [self.arrEducation objectAtIndex:4];

    }
    else if ([self.arrFields objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+2]){

        lblDetail1.text = [self.arrHobbies objectAtIndex:0];

        lblDetail2.text = [self.arrHobbies objectAtIndex:1];

        lblDetail3.text = [self.arrHobbies objectAtIndex:2];

        lblDetail4.text = [self.arrHobbies objectAtIndex:3];

        lblDetail5.text = [self.arrHobbies objectAtIndex:4];

    }
    else if([self.arrFields objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+3]){

        lblDetail1.text = [self.arrInterest objectAtIndex:0];

        lblDetail2.text = [self.arrInterest objectAtIndex:1];

        lblDetail3.text = [self.arrInterest objectAtIndex:2];

        lblDetail4.text = [self.arrInterest objectAtIndex:3];

        lblDetail5.text = [self.arrInterest objectAtIndex:4];

}

    if(selectedRowIndex && indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex.row) {

          vw.hidden=FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
          vw.hidden=TRUE;
    }
    return cell;

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


   if(selectedRowIndex)
   {
       [tableView reloadData];
    }
    selectedRowIndex = indexPath ;
    NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);

    [tableView beginUpdates];

    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    [tableView endUpdates];

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if(selectedRowIndex && indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex.row) {

        return 222;

    }
    else{

        return 44;

    }

}

@end
```

Comment: Problem is with if condition. It will always satisfy condition for first block.

Comment: Why are you passing hardcode indexes in array just remove your if conditions and pass indexPath.row for index value.

Comment: Exactly that is the problem. @Uttam Sinha

Comment: And yes I have changed that @Arpit.

Comment: yes you are passing harcoded index value and at every row first condition is satisfied that's why same value is coming for all row

Comment: @iPeter - Do if(indexPath.row == 0){ }else if(indexPath.row == 1){ } like this.

Comment: @UttamSinha Can you please help me in one more thing? How to collapse the expanded cell when I touch second time on the same row?

Comment: @iPeter - Define one more indexPath as NSIndexPath *expandedRowIndex; On didSelectRow assign selectedIndex to expandedRowIndex. in cellForRowAtIndexPath check expandedRowIndex!=nil and indexPath.row equal expandedRowIndex,row and your if, else conditions as usual. So that first time it will not expand. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

KMAccordionTableViewController do it for you.

http://github.com/klevison/KMAccordionTableViewController

Comment: Dude I have seen almost every tutorials and downloaded many source codes. I know every one of them will fulfil my requirement. But I want to make it on my own. Can you rectify where am I wrong in my code? I can tell you that my checkin in cellForRowAtindexPath is wrong and I am not getting the idea what to do there. Can you plz help me? @Klevison Matias

Answer (score 0):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

...

if([self.arrFields objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]) {  

...
```

If define it allways "true". Maybe you want to check:

```
if(indexPath.row == 0) {}
else if(indexPath.row == 1) {}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be using sections.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 5;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    if (section == 0) {
        return self.arrFields.count;
    } else if (section == 1) {
        return self.arrPersonalInfo.count;
    } else if (section == 2) {
        return self.arrEducation.count;
    } else if (section == 3) {
        return self.arrHobbies.count;
    } else if (section == 4) {
        return self.arrInterest.count;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

If you have a fully tableView with sections etc working, then work on the collapsing/expanding:

- set empty array if collapsed, and the proper array if expanded
- use self.tableView **reloadSections:withRowAnimation**

Comment: Ok dude! Lemme give it a try and I will get back to you. @dOM